# ASP.NET site with Anonymous authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I have am asp.net 3.5 web site with a asmx web service and a test aspx page (the page tests the web service using javascript). 
I need to run this site with anonymous authentication, so I setup the site in IIS as such.
Now, if I am trying to open the test page in the browser, I get 401.3-Unauthorized error.

Any ideas what should I do to fix it? Do I have to give read access for the physical file to Anonymous Login?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean 403 - Unauthorized, right?  503 is something different.

Comment: Just updated, it's 401.3

Comment: @marteljn - You have put me on the right track - the user that was setup for anonymous auth, didn't have permissions for the physical folder. I fixed that and now it's working fine. Make your last comment an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, what version of IIS are you using? Also if you are using the IIS mgr and you check anonymous authentication, you need to give it a valid username and password, have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

A 403 can mean several things.  It can mean you don't have authentication correctly configured, or it can mean that the ASP.NET worker process does not have rights to access the pages (the security is set to only allow you to access them, for instance).  There are other scenarios as well, but these are the two most common.